# getpwuid_r and getgrgid_r are slow, how can I cache them?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am writing a clone of `find` while learning C. When implementing the `-ls` option I've stumbled upon a problem that the `getpwuid_r` and `getgrgid_r` calls are really slow, the same applies to `getpwuid` and `getgrgid`. I need them to display the user/group names from ids provided by `stat.h`.

For example, listing the whole filesystem gets 3x slower:

```
# measurements were made 3 times and the fastest run was recorded

# with getgrgid_r

time ./myfind / -ls > list.txt

real    0m4.618s
user    0m1.848s
sys     0m2.744s


# getgrgid_r replaced with 'return "user";'

time ./myfind / -ls > list.txt

real    0m1.437s
user    0m0.572s
sys     0m0.832s
```

I wonder how GNU find maintains such a good speed. I've seen the [sources](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), but they are not exactly easy to understand and to apply without special types, macros etc:

```
time find / -ls > list.txt

real    0m1.544s
user    0m0.884s
sys     0m0.648s
```

I thought about caching the `uid - username` and `gid - groupname` pairs in a data structure. Is it a good idea? How would you implement it?

You can find my complete code [here](https://github.com/amq/myfind).

**UPDATE:**

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35821655/2913372) was exactly what I was looking for:

```
time ./myfind / -ls > list.txt

real    0m1.480s
user    0m0.696s
sys     0m0.736s
```

Here is a version based on `getgrgid` (if you don't require thread safety):

```
char *do_get_group(struct stat attr) {
  struct group *grp;

  static unsigned int cache_gid = UINT_MAX;
  static char *cache_gr_name = NULL;

  /* skip getgrgid if we have the record in cache */
  if (cache_gid == attr.st_gid) {
    return cache_gr_name;
  }

  /* clear the cache */
  cache_gid = UINT_MAX;

  grp = getgrgid(attr.st_gid);

  if (!grp) {
    /*
     * the group is not found or getgrgid failed,
     * return the gid as a string then;
     * an unsigned int needs 10 chars
     */
    char group[11];
    if (snprintf(group, 11, "%u", attr.st_gid) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: snprintf(): %s\n", program, strerror(errno));
      return "";
    }
    return group;
  }

  cache_gid = grp->gr_gid;
  cache_gr_name = grp->gr_name;

  return grp->gr_name;
}
```

`getpwuid`:

```
char *do_get_user(struct stat attr) {
  struct passwd *pwd;

  static unsigned int cache_uid = UINT_MAX;
  static char *cache_pw_name = NULL;

  /* skip getpwuid if we have the record in cache */
  if (cache_uid == attr.st_uid) {
    return cache_pw_name;
  }

  /* clear the cache */
  cache_uid = UINT_MAX;

  pwd = getpwuid(attr.st_uid);

  if (!pwd) {
    /*
     * the user is not found or getpwuid failed,
     * return the uid as a string then;
     * an unsigned int needs 10 chars
     */
    char user[11];
    if (snprintf(user, 11, "%u", attr.st_uid) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: snprintf(): %s\n", program, strerror(errno));
      return "";
    }
    return user;
  }

  cache_uid = pwd->pw_uid;
  cache_pw_name = pwd->pw_name;

  return pwd->pw_name;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Changed `long` to `unsigned int`.

**UPDATE 3:**

Added the cache clearing. It is absolutely necessary, because `pwd->pw_name` may point to a static area. `getpwuid` can overwrite its contents if it fails or simply when executed somewhere else in the program.

Also removed `strdup`. Since the output of `getgrgid` and `getpwuid` [should not be freed](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid), there is no need to require `free` for our wrapper functions.

Comment: This version with `getgrgid()` is definitely simpler than the other one.  Did you check if the same mechanism in `do_get_user` gains anything?  Also you should reset the cache with `cache_gid = -1;` if you call `getgrgid()` because you do not know if `cache_gr_name` is still valid if `getgrgid` fails.

Comment: @chqrlie: Completely the same applies to `getpwuid` / `do_get_user`. At first I thought it would be redundant to paste the code for it, but I have added it now. I don't think that clearing the cache is necessary, because even if the previous run of getgrgid failed, `cache_gid` won't be affected.

Comment: I have tried intentionally making `getgrgid` fail and setting `grp` to `NULL` randomly or if `gid` is > 10, and everything worked as expected. Even setting `grp = NULL;` right before `return strdup(cache_gr_name);` doesn't break anything. Can a failing `getgrgid` influence `cache_gr_name`, considering that user is freed in `do_ls`?

Comment: when you call `getgrgid`, the area of memory that was returned previously and especially `grp->gr_name` may become invalid.  It depends on the implementation.  You may not observe any bad side-effects on your system, but this proves nothing for other systems or other circumstances.  The value returned to the caller is a copy, so freeing it is recommended and has no effect on the original. You can avoid any problems by setting `cache_gid = -1` before calling `getgrgid`.

Comment: Another remark: an `unsigned int` may or may not require 10 characters, the size of `unsigned int` is system dependent, and it would be more consistent to use the proper format: `snprintf(user, 11, "%u", (unsigned int)attr.st_uid);`

Comment: @chqrlie you were right about the cache clearing, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timings indeed indicate a strong suspicion on these functions.

Looking at your function `do_get_group`, there are some issues:

- You use `sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX);` for every call to `do_get_group` and `do_get_user`, definitely cache that, it will not change during the lifetime of your program, but you will not gain much.
- You use `attr.st_uid` instead of `attr.st_gid`, which probably causes the lookup to fail for many files, possibly defeating the cacheing mechanism, if any.  Fix this first, this is a bug!
- You return values that should not be passed to `free()` by the caller, such as `grp->gr_name` and `""`.  You should always allocate the string you return.  The same issue is probably present in `do_get_user()`.

Here is a replacement for `do_get_group` with a one shot cache.  See if this improves the performance:

```
/*
 * @brief returns the groupname or gid, if group not present on the system
 *
 * @param attr the entry attributes from lstat
 *
 * @returns the groupname if getgrgid() worked, otherwise gid, as a string
 */
char *do_get_group(struct stat attr) {
    char *group;
    struct group grp;
    struct group *result;

    static size_t length = 0;
    static char *buffer = NULL;
    static gid_t cache_gid = -1;
    static char *cache_gr_name = NULL;

    if (!length) {
        /* only allocate the buffer once */
        long sysconf_length = sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX);

        if (sysconf_length == -1) {
            sysconf_length = 16384;
        }

        length = (size_t)sysconf_length;
        buffer = calloc(length, 1);
    }
    if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: malloc(): %s\n", program, strerror(errno));
        return strdup("");
    }

    /* check the cache */
    if (cache_gid == attr.st_gid) {
        return strdup(cache_gr_name);
    }

    /* empty the cache */
    cache_gid = -1;
    free(cache_gr_name);
    cache_gr_name = NULL;

    if (getgrgid_r(attr.st_gid, &grp, buffer, length, &result) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: getpwuid_r(): %s\n", program, strerror(errno));
        return strdup("");
    }

    if (result) {
        group = grp.gr_name;
    } else {
        group = buffer;
        if (snprintf(group, length, "%ld", (long)attr.st_gid) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: snprintf(): %s\n", program, strerror(errno));
            return strdup("");
        }
    }

    /* load the cache */
    cache_gid = attr.st_gid;
    cache_gr_name = strdup(group);

    return strdup(group);
}
```

Comment: To demonstrate this, try running the commands in the opposite order.

Comment: The slowdown is repeatable, I can run both commands 10 times in any order, and there will be always a ~3x difference.

Comment: OP is using `getgrgid_r` which is equal to `getgrgid` except that it doesn't store the data in a static buffer and is thus thread-safe.

Comment: @FUZxxl: A simple one shot cache should show substantial improvements.

Comment: The `sysconf` call is probably the fastest of all of these. On most systems, it is a simple table-lookup. Anyway, I still believe that you asking OP to use the non thread-safe functions `getgrgid` and `getpwuid` instead is a red herring and not going to help. And no, these functions are not allowed to cache the information as they are guaranteed to yield up-to-date results.

Comment: The timings are the same with `getpwuid` and `getgrgid`. You can see my code [here](https://github.com/amq/myfind/blob/master/main.c)

Comment: @amq: first try and fix the bug on `st_gid` and see if performance is increase.  Then use the replacement function I just posted and see if further improvements accur.  If so, you might want to do the same for `do_get_user` or implement a more general cacheing mechanism with an array.

Comment: Thank you! It worked great, I just needed to change `gid_t cache_gid` to `int cache_gid`. I've also added a `getgrgid`-based version.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the `getpwuid` and `getgrgid` calls are cached depends on how they are implemented and on how your system is configured. I recently wrote an implementation of `ls` and ran into a similar problem.

I found that on all modern systems I tested, the two functions are uncached unless you run the name service caching dæmon (nscd) in which case nscd makes sure that the cache stays up to date. It's easy to understand why this happens: Without an nscd, caching the information could lead to outdated output which is a violation of the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgrgid.html).

I don't think you should rely on these functions caching the group and passwd databases because they often don't. I implemented custom caching code for this purpose. If you don't require to have up-to-date information in case the database contents change during program execution, this is perfectly fine to do.

You can find my implementation of such a cache [here](https://gist.github.com/fuzxxl/9f84b8be7591897f8473). I'm not going to publish it on Stack Overflow as I do not desire to publish the code under the MIT license.